# How to change the Power BI export to Excel formatting issue?

Tags: excel, powerbi

When I export a table to excel some of the cells in the column are not in the same format as the other cells, how can change it so that all the cells have the same format?

In this example the first and third cells are correct but the middle cell is giving the number in a different format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excel is auto-detecting the format and seeing some of those as written in scientific numerical format.

See this SuperUser post for strategies to deal with that:

https://superuser.com/questions/861964/how-do-i-stop-excel-from-converting-value-0503e000-to-5-03e02-automatically/862073